# How can I remedy this if statement?

Tags: c++, if-statement, logic

I am trying to create a simple, 'fizzbuzz' program where every time a multiple of 3 is printed, 'fizz' is printed beside it and every time a multiple of 5 is printed, 'buzz' is printed beside it.
 However, what happens instead in this program is that the first if statement is true every time and the output is every number having, 'Buzz!' beside it. Why is this happening? What do I need to realize in order to program this correctly?

```
for(int index = 1; index <= 100; ++index) {
    cout << index << endl;
    if (index == 5, 10, 15, 20, 25, 30, 35, 40, 45, 50, 55, 60, 65, 70, 75, 80, 85, 90, 95, 100)
        cout << " Buzz!" << endl;
    else if(index == 3, 6, 9, 12, 15, 18, 21, 24, 27, 30, 33, 36, 39, 42, 45, 48, 51, 54, 57, 60, 63, 66, 69, 72, 75, 78, 81, 84, 87, 90, 93, 96, 99)
        cout << " Fizz!" << endl;
}
```

Comment: 1. These `if`s don't do what they think they do. 2. The way to check if a number is divisible by 5 is to compare the remainder of division by five to zero, i.e. `number%5 == 0`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The comma operator in C++ means something completely different - it separates two expressions, forgets the result of the first one and returns the value of the second one.

Therefore the first statement technically can be shortened to:

```
if (100) {
    ...
```

which is always true (any non-zero expression in C/C++ evaluates as true).

To avoid so many comparison you can actually use `%` operator.

```
if (i%5 == 0) {
    cout << " Buzz!" << endl;
}
else if (i%3 == 0) {
    cout << " Fizz!" << endl;
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much everyone. I will consider modulus from now on and fix this code with the information you gave me.

Answer (score 0):

This can easily be cleaned up using modulus (%).

```
for(int index = 1; index <= 100; ++index) {
    cout << index << endl;
    if (index % 5 == 0)
        cout << " Buzz!" << endl;
    else if(index % 3 == 0)
        cout << " Fizz!" << endl;
}
```